# Change key to value of same key in other dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm looking for the following, but I won't get it. I already tried with swapping key-value pairs, but that didn't work.

The thing I'm trying to obtain, consider 2 dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':20, 'c':100}
dict2 = {'a':'apple', 'b':'banana', 'c':'citrus'}
```

I'm trying to look for a new dictionary:

```
dict3 = {'apple':1, 'banana':20, 'citrus':100}
```

Can someone help me or give me some tips? (Both dictionaries are very large, so first I need to program it that way that it looks for the right key in dict2 - which is way larger than dict1 and not in same order as dict1).

Comment: `d3 = {d2[k]: d1[k] for k in d1}`? Do they always have the exact same keys?

Comment: Less lookups: `{v: dict1[k] for k, v in dict2.items()}`

Comment: They always have the same keys. I

Comment: What type is that weird `dict2` thing ? `dict-list` ? ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Use `iteritems()` to iteratete key and value of a dict.

```
for key, value in dict2.iteritems():
    dict3[value] = dict1[key]
```

For Python 3.x, `iteritems()` has been replaced with simply `items()`, which returns a set-like view backed by the dict, like `iteritems()` but even better. This is also available in 2.7 as `viewitems()`. The operation `items()` will work for both 2 and 3, but in 2 it will return a list of the dictionary's `(key, value)` pairs, which will not reflect changes to the dict that happen after the `items()` call. If you want the 2.x behavior in 3.x, you can call `list(d.items())`.